# SQL - Group by Filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

So I have a query to pull the sums of a column > 1 and I group certain departments by a few users, like so:

```
SELECT
   t.DEPARTMENT_ID
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN t.VALUE > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Results

FROM TABLE t

WHERE t.USER_ID = 000
OR t.DEPARTMENT ID = 1001
   AND t.USER_ID IN
('01'
,'02'
)

OR t.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1002
   AND t.USER_ID IN
('02'
,'03'
)

GROUP BY t.DEPARTMENT ID
```

The results would be like:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID    Results
1001             5
1002             7
```

Now, that works because there departments are specified in the column, and I just Group by it.

But, what if I wanted to create my own teams (see teams in notes --) and group by team leaders? For example:

```
SELECT
   t.DEPARTMENT_ID
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN t.VALUE > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 

FROM TABLE t

WHERE t.USER_ID = 000   

--Team_1 
   OR t.DEPARTMENT ID = 1001
AND t.USER_ID IN
('01'
,'02'
)

OR t.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1002
   AND t.USER_ID IN
('02'
,'03'
)

-- Team_2
OR t.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1003
   AND t.USER_ID IN
('05'
,'06'
)
```

I would like the results to turn up like this:

```
TEAMS      RESULTS
Team_1     6
Team_2     4
```

**How would I group by Team?**

Comment: Hi Kazzi, your question is not clear. Can you provide DDL, some sample data, and the expected result? Using SQL Fiddle or similar online service would be very helpful.

Comment: No one can help you if no one can understand you.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'll re-edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a case expression in select & group by and remove department_ID from select & group by.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.DEPARTMENT ID = 1001 AND t.USER_ID IN ('01','02') 
              OR t.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1002 AND t.USER_ID IN ('02','03') then 'Team1'
            WHEN t.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1003 AND t.USER_ID IN ('05','06') then 'Team2' END as Team
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t.VALUE > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as Results 
FROM TABLE t
WHERE t.USER_ID = 000   
--Team_1 
   OR (t.DEPARTMENT ID = 1001
  AND t.USER_ID IN ('01','02')
   OR t.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1002
  AND t.USER_ID IN ('02','03'))
-- Team_2
   OR (t.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1003
  AND t.USER_ID IN ('05','06'))
GROUP BY CASE WHEN t.DEPARTMENT ID = 1001 AND t.USER_ID IN ('01','02') 
                OR t.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1002 AND t.USER_ID IN ('02','03') then 'Team1'
              WHEN t.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1003 AND t.USER_ID IN ('05','06') then 'Team2' END
```

Guessing on ()'s for desired results. in the where clause based on the team comments.

Comment: `AND` has precedence over `OR`..you should use parentheses in `where` appropriately.

Comment: No argument here; but the original post/ where didn't have em. so the desired results are at best ambiguous.  though this beggs the question since user_ID = 000 and it's not being evaluated, if any such records exist they will show up and group by will have a null result which doesn't match expected...

Answer (score 3):

use CASE statement:

```
select case
       when t.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1001 and t.USER_ID in ('01', '02') then 'Team 1'
       when t.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1002 and t.USER_ID in ('02', '03') then 'Team 2'
       when t.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1003 and t.USER_ID in ('05', '06') then 'Team 3'
       end as Teams,
      sum(case when t.value > 1 then 1 else 0 end)
from TABLE t
group by 
      case when t.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1001 and t.USER_ID in ('01', '02') then 'Team 1'
           when t.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1002 and t.USER_ID in ('02', '03') then 'Team 2'
           when t.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1003 and t.USER_ID in ('05', '06') then 'Team 3'
      end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can build a list of `VALUES()` and join with it. Much simpler than repeating yourself three times:

```
SELECT teams.name, SUM(CASE WHEN t.VALUE > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Results
FROM (VALUES
    ('team 1', 1001, 1),
    ('team 1', 1001, 2),
    ('team 2', 1002, 3),
    ('team 2', 1002, 4),
    ('team 3', 1001, 5),
    ('team 3', 1001, 6)
) AS teams(name, deptid, userid)
INNER JOIN t ON teams.deptid = t.DEPARTMENT_ID AND teams.userid = t.USER_ID
GROUP BY teams.name
```

Comment: This seems so much saner!